# app call recorder Works on Android devices less than 7.0.0 ... but does not work with Android version 8.0.0 Oreo

Tags: android, foreground

My app call recorder works on Android devices less than 7.0.0, but does not work with Android 8.0.0 Oreo. It records all calls, but in the Android 8.0.0 Oreo does not show notifications and does not record any calls.
How to use a foreground service in Android?

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import com.callrecorder.R;
import com.callrecorder.helper.SecurePreferences;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

public class CallRecorderService extends Service {
    public static File amr;
    public static final String ACTION = "com.callrecorder.CALL_RECORD";
    public static final String STATE = "STATE";
    public static final String START = "START";
    public static final String STORAGE = "STORAGE";
    public static final String INCOMING = "INCOMING";
    public static final String OUTGOING = "OUTGOING";
    public static final String BEGIN = "BEGIN";
    public static final String END = "END";

    protected static final String TAG = CallRecorderService.class.getName();
    protected static final boolean DEBUG = false;
    private static final int RECORDING_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    private static final String AMR_DIR = "/AutoCallRecording/";
    private static final String IDLE = "";
    private static final String INCOMING_CALL_SUFFIX = "_inCall";
    private static final String OUTGOING_CALL_SUFFIX = "_outCall";

    private Context cntx;
    private volatile String fileNamePrefix = IDLE;
    private volatile MediaRecorder recorder;
    private volatile PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    private volatile boolean isMounted = false;
    private volatile boolean isInRecording = false;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        this.cntx = getApplicationContext();
        this.prepareAmrDir();
        log("service create");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        log("service destory");
        this.stopRecording();
        this.cntx = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (null == intent || !ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(STATE);
        String phoneNo = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        log("state: " + state + " phoneNo: " + phoneNo);
        if (OUTGOING.equals(state)) {
            fileNamePrefix = "(" + phoneNo + ")" + OUTGOING_CALL_SUFFIX;
        } else if (INCOMING.equals(state)) {
            fileNamePrefix = "(" + phoneNo + ")" + INCOMING_CALL_SUFFIX;
        } else if (BEGIN.equals(state)) {
            if (SecurePreferences.getBooleanPreference(this, Constants.PREF_RECORD_CALLS)) {
                startRecording();
            }
        } else if (END.equals(state)) {
            stopRecording();
        } else if (STORAGE.equals(state)) {
            String mountState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(mountState)) {
                prepareAmrDir();
            } else {
                isMounted = false;
            }
            if (!isInRecording) {
                stopSelf();
            }
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return cntx;
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        updateNotification(false);
        if (isInRecording) {
            isInRecording = false;
            try {
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
                recorder = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            releaseWakeLock();

//          MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(amr.getAbsolutePath()));
//          int duration = 0;
//          if (mp != null) {
//              duration = mp.getDuration();
//          }

//          if (duration > 2000) {

                if (SecurePreferences.getBooleanPreference(this, Constants.PREF_SAVE_RECORDING)) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(CallRecorderService.this, AutoRunReceiver.class);
                    String ACTION_SHOW_ALERT_DIALOG = "com.callrecorder.SHOW_ALERT_DIALOG";
                    intent.setAction(ACTION_SHOW_ALERT_DIALOG);
                    intent.putExtra("absolutepath", amr.getAbsolutePath());
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
//          } else {
//              File file = new File(amr.getAbsolutePath());
//              boolean deleted = file.delete();
//          }

            stopSelf();
            log("call recording stopped");

        }
    }

    private void updateNotification(Boolean status) {

        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

        if (status) {

            CharSequence contentTitle = "CallRecorder Status";
            CharSequence contentText = "Recording call from channel...";
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, CallRecorderService.class);

            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(contentText)).setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentText(contentText);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(alarmIntent);
            mNotificationManager.notify(RECORDING_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        } else {
            mNotificationManager.cancel(RECORDING_NOTIFICATION_ID);
        }
    }

    private String getDateTimeString() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'_'HHmmss");
        Date now = new Date();
        return sdf.format(now);
    }

    private String getMonthString() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM");
        Date now = new Date();
        return sdf.format(now);
    }

    private String getDateString() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        Date now = new Date();
        return sdf.format(now);
    }

    private String getTimeString() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
        Date now = new Date();
        return sdf.format(now);
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        if (SecurePreferences.getBooleanPreference(this, Constants.PREF_NOTIFICATION_ENABLE)) {
            updateNotification(true);
        } else {
            updateNotification(false);
        }
        if (!isMounted) {
            stopRecording();
            updateNotification(false);
            return;
        }
        try {

            int format = SecurePreferences.getIntegerPreference(this, Constants.PREF_AUDIO_FORMAT);

            String exten = format == 1 ? ".3gpp" : format == 2 ? ".mpg" : ".amr";
            amr = new File(Constants.StoragePath + getDateTimeString() + "_" + fileNamePrefix + exten);
            log("Prepare recording in " + amr.getAbsolutePath());
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(format);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            recorder.setOutputFile(amr.getAbsolutePath());
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();
            isInRecording = true;
            acquireWakeLock();
            log("Recording in " + amr.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w(TAG, e);
        }
    }

    private void prepareAmrDir() {
        isMounted = Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        if (!isMounted)
            return;
        File amrRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + AMR_DIR);
        if (!amrRoot.isDirectory())
            amrRoot.mkdir();
    }

    private void log(String info) {
        if (DEBUG && isMounted) {
            File log = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + AMR_DIR + "log_"
                    + getMonthString() + ".txt");
            try {
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(log, true));
                try {
                    synchronized (out) {
                        out.write(getDateString() + getTimeString());
                        out.write(" ");
                        out.write(info);
                        out.newLine();
                    }
                } finally {
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void acquireWakeLock() {
        if (wakeLock == null) {
            log("Acquiring wake lock");
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
            wakeLock.acquire();
        }

    }

    private void releaseWakeLock() {
        if (wakeLock != null && wakeLock.isHeld()) {
            wakeLock.release();
            wakeLock = null;
            log("Wake lock released");
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
package com.callrecorder;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class AutoRunReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String ACTION_SHOW_ALERT_DIALOG = "com.callrecorder.SHOW_ALERT_DIALOG";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (null == intent)
            return;
        Intent i = new Intent(CallRecorderService.ACTION);
        i.setPackage("com.callrecorder");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_SHOW_ALERT_DIALOG)) {
            Intent intentDialog = new Intent(context, DialogClass.class);
            String absolutepath = intent.getStringExtra("absolutepath");
            intentDialog.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intentDialog.putExtra("absolutepath", absolutepath);
            context.startActivity(intentDialog);
        }
        if (Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            i.putExtra(CallRecorderService.STATE, CallRecorderService.OUTGOING);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER,
                    intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER));
        } else if (TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED.equals(intent
                .getAction())) {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {
                i.putExtra(CallRecorderService.STATE,
                        CallRecorderService.INCOMING);
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, intent
                        .getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER));
            } else if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(state)) {
                i.putExtra(CallRecorderService.STATE, CallRecorderService.BEGIN);
            } else if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state)) {
                i.putExtra(CallRecorderService.STATE, CallRecorderService.END);
            }
        } else if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            i.putExtra(CallRecorderService.STATE, CallRecorderService.START);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED)
                || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED)) {
            i.putExtra(CallRecorderService.STATE, CallRecorderService.STORAGE);
        } else {
            return;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, CallRecorderService.class));
        } else {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, CallRecorderService.class));
        }


        Log.d(CallRecorderService.TAG,
                "AutoRunReceiver startService "
                        + i.getStringExtra(CallRecorderService.STATE) + ":"
                        + i.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

---

```
android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

Comment: Just set android:targetSdkVersion="28" and check.

Comment: @DPrince Prince Not Working Because We must use` startForeground(1, notification);  ` and 
`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
         context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, CallRecorderService.class));
     } else {
         context.startService(new Intent(context, CallRecorderService.class));
     }'

But I did not know how to use it :/
  `code`

Comment: It's working in Nougat then what type of error you got in Oreo ?

Comment: @DPrince There is no error. All of this does not record calls and does not Show the notification

Comment: From your callRecording method start, There you will set throwable and get the actual problem. And then you will show that log to me. as well compare the both version log.